# GitHub Action capture filename generated by vsce

Tags: vscode-extensions

gulp has been retired from the vscode extension packaging process.

My github workflow used to contain this boilerplate that magically set the packageName

```
  - name: Package
    env:
      VSIX_PACKAGE_PATH: ${{ steps.setup.outputs.packageName }}
    run: npx gulp package
```

This can be replaced with `vsce package` but that doesn't set the packageName. I could perhaps construct it given the naming rules use info that's present in `package.json` but is there some way to capture the name of the generated vsix file into `steps.setup.outputs.packageName`?

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the old version and went through the gulpfile to see what it does. It prepares localisation files and other things, but for the purposes of this question it boiled down to specifying the name of the output file. Webpack has an option for that, and the required value is already being put into an environment variable, so I used it. This seemed to be successful as the next steps began the find the files they were expecting.

```
  - name: Package
    env:
      VSIX_PACKAGE_PATH: ${{ steps.setup.outputs.packageName }}
    run: webpack --mode production --output-path $VSIX_PACKAGE_PATH
```

The question was how to capture the name of the file. You don't do that, you start with the name and you tell the packager what it is.